# SQL Query COUNT with two Joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a SQL Query from 3 tables (messages, user_comment_messages and user_like_messages), I need to get a list of each message with the total number of likes and comments, actually I'm trying with this:

```
SELECT m.id, COUNT(c.id) AS t_comment, COUNT(l.id) AS t_like
FROM messages m
JOIN user_comment_messages c ON c.message_id = m.id
JOIN user_like_messages l ON l.message_id = m.id
GROUP BY m.id;
```

When I execute the query I get the same value in the two columns and is incorrect. So I've tried with a subquery:

```
SELECT m.id,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_comment_messages c WHERE m.id = c.message_id) AS t_like,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_like_messages l WHERE m.id = l.message_id) AS t_comment
FROM messages m
ORDER BY m.id
```

This works well, but on my development environment I can't use subselects, only joins. Is there another way to accomplish that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use `distinct` in `count` function to count distinct occurrences of `commentid`s and `likeid`s:

```
SELECT m.id, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) AS t_comment, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT l.id) AS t_like
FROM messages m
LEFT JOIN user_comment_messages c ON c.message_id = m.id
LEFT JOIN user_like_messages l ON l.message_id = m.id
GROUP BY m.id;
```

Comment: Do you need an outer join for the messages/likes?

Comment: @Drumbeg, yes there should be left join if any table doesn't have rows in it.

Comment: @Drumbeg, ??? I have edited my answer based on your comment and upvoted your comment...............Count will ignore nulls

Comment: this worked flawlessly! The Distinct inside the Count was the key, thanks @GiorgiNakeuri

Answer (score 0):

You use the LEFT JOIN, by this you can get all message either having like or comment or have no like or comment.

```
SELECT m.id, 
       IFNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT c.id),0) AS t_comment, 
       IFNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT l.id),0) AS t_like
FROM messages m
LEFT JOIN user_comment_messages c ON c.message_id = m.id
JOIN user_like_messages l ON l.message_id = m.id
GROUP BY m.id;
```